# Android Staggered GridView with Horizontal Scroll

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, staggered-gridview

I am using maurycy's staggered grid view from https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView. This library supports only vertical scrolling. I would like to implement horizontal scrolling.

How is it possible. I am expecting to form a layout similar to 500px android app which has dynamic imageview layouts with a heterogeneous pattern. Pls refer the screenshot.[image: This is a dynamic layout]

[image: This is the next page on swiping horizontally]

Comment: I've used a example for Horizontal Scroll, check it out : https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary